# Making a combination of coefficients for a range?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am having trouble making a combination of coefficients. Basically I have a list of items and want to get all the unique combinations of coefficients for them like this:

```
dog:1 cat:1
dog:2 cat:1
dog:3 cat:1
dog:1 cat:2
dog:2 cat:2
```

I'm not really sure the best way of doing this(dynamic programming, recursion,brute force,etc..) so I tried to start by doing a recursion:

```
list = ["dog", "cat"]

coeff = [1] * len(list)
main_queue = []

def recursion(k, list):
    for item in list[0:k-1]:
        for data in range(5):
            coeff_temp = coeff
            coeff_temp[k] = data
            main_queue.append(coeff_temp)
            #print item, data

    if k == (len(list)-1):
        return
    else:
        recursion(k+1, list)

recursion(0, list)

print "*" * 30

for x in main_queue:
    print x
```

output is:

```
******************************
[4, 1]
[4, 1]
[4, 1]
[4, 1]
[4, 1]
```

It only changes the last entry in the main queue I made.  What am I doing wrong?

p.s. Is this the best way to do this(the range is between 1-5 and there will be about 20-30 items in the list..am I better off using dynamic programming)?

Comment: I don't understand from your description what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please could provide a *complete* example that would clearly specify the input and the expected output.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I have an example of the intended output..What part are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: You haven't shown us the input!

Comment: @aix What do you mean? I have an example of the output and in my sample code I have the list that I'm using to generate the results

Comment: The input is the list = ["dog", "cat", "monkey", "pig"]

Comment: How does that correspond with the output at the top? Where do "monkey" and "pig" come in?

Comment: I do not see the connection between the given input, your description of your goal, and the given output. And the actual output is so different that it doesn't seem to be related.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I deleted that..I was testing it with a larger list so I can try to pinpoint where it failed.  Its edited now.

Comment: OK, what's the actual output and how is it even close to related to the sample output?

Comment: edited the code to match the output sample

Comment: Well, for one thing, you will end up with 5**30 =`= 9.31 * 10**20 combinations (that's about 931 billion billion). At a million per second, it will take about 30 million years to go through them all.

Comment: Your actual and intended output are not even in the same format!

Comment: @HughBothwell is that considering using all variables? its not building up so there are no unused variables

Comment: OK, so now that we have the output mostly straightened out, what does "combination of coefficients" mean? I am still having trouble seeing what mathematical process would get the given output from the given input.

Comment: I *think* he wants all combinations of 0 to 4 dogs, 0 to 4 cats, 0 to 4 monkeys, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is this line:

```
coeff_temp = coeff
```

That doesn't make a copy of `coeff`: that makes a reference to the same object. When you modify it on the next line:

```
coeff_temp[k] = data
```

You're modifying every one you've inserted so far - they're all the same list!

To actually copy the list, use:

```
coeff_temp = list(coeff)
```

or

```
coeff_temp = coeff[:]
```

---

Here's the best solution to your problem:

```
import itertools
data = {
    "dog": xrange(1, 5),
    "cat": xrange(1, 5)
    #add more here...
}
combinations = (dict(zip(data.keys(), c)) for c in itertools.product(*data.values()))

for c in combinations:
    print c
```

Comment: Thanks Eric,I realized I made another mistake as well I used list as a variable so I used your example and changed the variable name but now I get an error `TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable`  on the first for loop in the recursion function

Comment: @Error_404 Then you're still using `list` as a variable.

Comment: your right, there was one instance I missed. It seems to kind of work now but there' duplicate results.

Comment: @Error_404: Have another look. I made it generic

Comment: I just noticed that..thanks.  And thanks for your answer/help.

Answer (score 2):

```
data = ["dog", "cat"]
upto = 4

def all_combos(items, upto):
    if items < 1:
        yield []
    else:
        for r in range(upto+1):
            for rest in all_combos(items-1, upto):
                yield [r] + rest

for coeffs in all_combos(len(data), upto):
    print ", ".join("{}s: {}".format(n, coeff) for n,coeff in zip(data,coeffs))
```

results in

```
dogs: 0, cats: 0
dogs: 0, cats: 1
dogs: 0, cats: 2
dogs: 0, cats: 3
dogs: 0, cats: 4
dogs: 1, cats: 0
dogs: 1, cats: 1
dogs: 1, cats: 2
dogs: 1, cats: 3
dogs: 1, cats: 4
dogs: 2, cats: 0
dogs: 2, cats: 1
dogs: 2, cats: 2
dogs: 2, cats: 3
dogs: 2, cats: 4
dogs: 3, cats: 0
dogs: 3, cats: 1
dogs: 3, cats: 2
dogs: 3, cats: 3
dogs: 3, cats: 4
dogs: 4, cats: 0
dogs: 4, cats: 1
dogs: 4, cats: 2
dogs: 4, cats: 3
dogs: 4, cats: 4
```

which is what you're after. *Keep in mind* that the number of combinations will be `(len(data))**upto` which increases explosively as data and upto grow.

**Edit:** as has been pointed out, another way to achieve this is

```
from itertools import product

def all_combos(items, upto):
    return product(*(range(upto+1) for i in range(items)))
```

Comment: Wouldn't `itertools.product` be a simpler way to get this output?  (I share the general confusion about what the OP wants; the example given doesn't match his later comments.)

Comment: @DSM: Definitely. See my answer for how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that what you want is an N-digit base-M number, where N is the number of items in the list, and M is the number of possible values for each.

Just for example, if you had 3 items in the list, and wanted values from 1 through 4 for each, you'd use a 3 digit base 3 number. Since your first digit is `1`, you'd add one to each digit as you assign it to the list item.

In this, the first column is the actual number as you count, and the second column is the same number with 1 added to each digit, then the values assigned to each of three animals:

```
000   111     cat 1 dog 1 hamster 1
001   112     cat 1 dog 1 hamster 2
002   113     cat 1 dog 1 hamster 3
010   121     cat 1 dog 2 hamster 1
011   122     cat 1 dog 2 hamster 2
012   123     cat 1 dog 2 hamster 3
020   131     cat 1 dog 3 hamster 1
021   132     cat 1 dog 3 hamster 2
022   133     cat 1 dog 3 hamster 3
100   211     cat 2 dog 1 hamster 1
```

and so on for the remaining 3-digit base-3 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see itertools lib http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html where you can find combinations() function, it must help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want combinations, then recursion is the correct answer almost all of the time.

There is a problem with your code: Inside the `recursion` function, when you say `coeff_temp = coeff` you are copying the *reference* to `coeff`, so your are just appending the same list every time. That's why . Otherwise the method seems fine to me.

Change the line

```
coeff_temp = coeff
```

to

```
coeff_temp = list(coeff)
```

to copy the list, and keep going on from  there.

The itertools module is a fine solution for combinations.

Comment: Sorry, @Eric already answered this same issue as I was writing my answer so I didn't saw it until I published. The credit should be for him.

Comment: You got there first, while I was typing - look at the times. However, your reasoning is wrong - the fact that `coeff` is global is irrelevant.

Comment: @Eric: Surely my explanation was not clear enough. I was trying to say exactly the same as you, that he was using a reference to the same list. I see now that it is not really clear, and I have fixed it. Thanks for the comment.